# Include zeros in value_counts pandas categorial data

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-up question for a question I asked previously. The old question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59427617/6814154), I received an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59427672/6814154) from [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael).

Now I want to plot the grades.

For plotting all grades I can do

```
counts_gardes = df1['new'].value_counts(sort=False)
counts_gardes.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

However, I could not figure out how to plot per grade group including zero counts.

```
counts_gardes_group = df1['new'].value_counts(sort=False)
counts_gardes_group.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

I would like to also include zero counts for `F` in the plotted figures. I tried the solutions provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520283/6814154), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340060/6814154) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24501) but they did not work. The first returns all grades, while the latter gives an error stating that `index` does not have `levels`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Well the problem is that if there are no `F`s, then these can not be counted. Pandas simply does not know that something like an `F` exists.

Comment: [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) variables would work here. See the [Categorical data Operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#operations) section of the Pandas User's Guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with swap order (if necessary) of list of all grades and if not match replace to `0`:

```
grade_leters = ['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D','D-', 'F']

counts_gardes_group = (df1['new'].value_counts(sort=False)
                                 .reindex(grade_leters[::-1], fill_value=0))
counts_gardes_group.plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
new_index = sorted(set([x[0] for x in df1['new'].cat.categories]), reverse=True)
counts_gardes_group = df1['new'].str[0].value_counts(sort=False).reindex(
     new_index, fill_value=0
)

counts_gardes_group.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```